# Next.js server side authentification in app layout

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm migrating a simple React App to Next.js. The app is publicly accessible but you can log in to access some features. Many components are slightly different when logged in. For example the header shows a menu to access your profile.

My problem is that when logged in the server and client renders differs so Next throws me an error. The connection is held by a bearerToken stored in a cookie on the client so automatically passed to each request.

I've seen on the official documentation that to authenticate your server you can use getServerSideProps() on each page. My problem is that I also need the authentification on the _app.tsx entry file so the layout of my app that display the header on all pages can render accordingly.

Also I'm using a network library that encapsulate my App with a context so any request inside gets automatically authenticated. I need somehow to pass the cookie to that library in my _app.tsx. I tried to do sometking like this :

```js
interface Props extends AppProps {
  cookie?: string;
}

function App({ Component, pageProps, cookie }: Props) {
  return (
    <StrictMode>
      <ApiContext cookie={cookie}>
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </ApiContext>
    </StrictMode>
  );
}

App.getInitialProps = ({ ctx }: AppContextType) => {
  return {
    cookie: ctx.req?.headers.cookie,
  };
};

export default App;
```

The cookie is passed correctly to my App but it seems to remove **Component** and **pageProps** props from it. I can't find the correct typing for the getInitialProps() function but when I console.log() the parameter it seems quite similar to AppContextType and it doesn't contains **Component** and **pageProps** props.

How am I supposed to do such a thing ? Is there a best way to do what I'm trying to achieved ? Since there is so few documentation and topics about that I guess that I'm not doing it the right way but I can't find anything better. How can you simply match the server and client render when using changing layouts based on authentification ? It seems quite common.

Thank you

I tried to use the getInitialProps() function to pass a cookie props to my App. Which is basically just the string of cookies passed from the client. It works but it seems to overwrite all props on the App and so break the whole thing. I was expecting to just add a new prop to my App component but it seems to set them all.